# How to make a Graph Visualization in Tensorflow v2 using Tensorboard?

Tags: keras, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0, graph-visualization, resnet

Actually I have two related problems. First of all is it possible to use Graph Visualization in Tfv2 ? Because I couldn't write a code to show my architecure so I didn't know my design is correct.

Second problem is my network has got training and validation accuracies are just %50. I used ResNet architecture. Here is my ResNet block and have used it in main network structure for 6 times. My GPU is not best so I have to use filter size 16 or 32:

```
class ResnetBlock(tf.keras.Model):

def __init__(self, residual_path=False):
    super(ResnetBlock, self).__init__()

    self.residual_path = residual_path

    self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size = (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=13))
    self.bn2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.993)
    self.relu2 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')

    self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=13))
    self.bn3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.993)
    self.relu3 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')



def call(self, inputs, training=None):

    x0 = inputs

    x = self.conv2(inputs)
    x = self.bn2(x, training=training)
    x = self.relu2(x)

    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = self.bn3(x, training=training)
    x = self.relu3(x)        



    x = x + x0    

    return x
```

Also here is the main network structure:

class ResNet(tf.keras.Model):

```
def __init__(self, num_blocks ,num_classes, **kwargs):
    super(ResNet, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.num_blocks = num_blocks

    self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (7,7), strides=(2,2), padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=13))
    self.bn1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.993)
    self.relu1 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')
    self.mps1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))


    self.blocks = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name='dynamic-blocks')


    for block_number in range(num_blocks):
        block = ResnetBlock(residual_path=True)        
        self.blocks.add(block)


    self.final_bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    self.avg_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)

def call(self, inputs, training=None):

    x = self.conv1(inputs)
    x = self.bn1(x, training=training)
    x = self.relu1(x) 
    x = self.mps1(x)

    out = self.blocks(x, training=training)



    out = self.final_bn(out, training=training)
    out = tf.nn.relu(out)

    out = self.avg_pool(out)
    out = self.fc(out)


    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

For your graph visualization, easiest way is to call:

```
net = ResNet(num_blocks, num_classes)
net.compile(...)
net.summary(...)
```

You can look at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#summary) for the arguments.

You can also test the [`keras.utils.plot_model` function](https://keras.io/visualization/) (I don't know if it works well with TF networks.

Finally, you fit your model for 1 epoch of 1 step, adding a [TensorBoard callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard). Then, using [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/get_started) you can get a very detailled graphical representation of your model.

Kind,
Alexis.

P.S: I do not really understand your second problem. Sorry.

Comment: I have already tried all of four methods that you suggested before asked here. But couldn't reach any solution except that summary method can be useful. Second problem was low accuracy rate for both training and validation respect to network architecture. But that's not a problem right now. Thank you for your kind respond